# Espacio entre botones bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Saludos a todos estoy agregando botones a mi pagina html con bootstrap 3.7 la cual se ve bien:
[image: actual]

El problema surge al visualizarlo en dispositivos mobiles es decir el espacio que se visualiza horizontalmente se pierde en los mobiles:

[image: en dispisitivos mobiles]

de esa forma se ve en dispositivos mobiles, el codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarCuenta">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"> Agregar</i> 
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"> Reporte</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

quiza estoy usando mal bootstrap, agradeceria su ayuda de antemano..!!

Comment: Bootstrap tiene en su CSS definida la clase `.btn` con la propiedad `margin-botton: 0;` por defecto. Puedes cambiar ese valor `0` por `10px` (por ejemplo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las clases de bootstrap para indicar las columnas se agrupan según el tamaño de la pantalla. Para Bootstrap 3.3.7 tienes [lo siguiente](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options):

```
Container width   None (auto)   750px       970px       1170px
Class prefix      .col-xs-      .col-sm-    .col-md-    .col-lg-
```

Cuando la pantalla es de 970px de ancho (o más), la clase `col-md-2` actúa. Una vez que la pantalla se reduce, esa clase deja de tener efecto y los botones ocupan el 100% del ancho (cada uno).

Prueba a poner lo siguiente:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-block btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarCuenta">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"> Agregar</i> 
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"> Reporte</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Así los dos botones deberían estar en la misma fila

Comment: muchas gracias.. pensaba que solo habia que establecer un col dentro de la clase pero veo que se debe definir para cada tipo tamaño de dispositivo